# Why doesnt my elastic search python script go to the next forwarder?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

Why doesnt my elastic search python script go to the next forwarder?

It seems to stop after 1 forwarder in my for loop, im expecting it to go to the next one

```
def build_query(start_date, end_date):

    start_date = "now-1d/d"
    end_date = "now/d"

    forwaders = (
    "SVGCEXABEC01",
    "SVGCEXABEC03",
    "SV04EXABEC02",
    "SV04EXABEC03",
    "SV07EXABEC01",
    "SV07EXABEC02",
    "SV07EXABEC03",
    "SVGCEXABEC02")
    for forwarder in forwaders:
        print(forwarder)
        query = {
            "size": 10_000,
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "query_string": {
                                "analyze_wildcard": True,
                                "default_field": "message",
                                "query": f'forwarder:"{forwarder}" AND (host.keyword:/LN.*/ OR host.keyword:/PC.*/ OR host.keyword:/TB.*/)', 
# noqa: E501
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                    "gte": start_date,
                                    "lte": end_date,
                                    "time_zone": LOCAL_UTC_OFF_SET,
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                    "must_not": [],
                }
            },
        "aggs": {
            "1": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "dest_host.keyword",
                    "size": 9_999,
                    "shard_size": 9_999,
                    "order": {"_count": "asc"},
                },
            },
        },
        }
        return query
```

It should go to the next forwarder, but it stops after the first one...
Can someone please help!!
This is what i tried:

```
def main():
    args = parse_args()
    if args.config_file:
        config = load_config(
            args.config_file, ("server", "port", "username", "password")
        )
    else:
        config = {}
    server = config["server"]
    port = config["port"]
    username = config["username"]
    password = config["password"]
    days = args.days
    start = args.start
    end = args.end

    forwaders = (
    "SVGCEXABEC01",
    "SVGCEXABEC03",
    "SV04EXABEC02",
    "SV04EXABEC03",
    "SV07EXABEC01",
    "SV07EXABEC02",
    "SV07EXABEC03",
    "SVGCEXABEC02")

    
    
    total_results_counter: Any = Counter()
    for start_date, end_date in time_range_slices(
        hour_slice=1,
        start=start,
        end=end,
        days=days,
    ):
        for forwader in forwaders:

            query = build_query(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, forwader=forwader)

            try:

                time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now()
                print(
                    f"Time Stamp: {time_stamp} | Start: {start_date} | End: {end_date} | ",
                    end="",
                    flush=True,
                )
                session = DataLakeSession(server, port, username, password)
                
                results = run_agg_query(session=session, query=query)
                parsed_results = parse_agg_results(results)

                print(f"Total: {len(parsed_results)}", flush=True)
                total_results_counter.update(parsed_results)

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error getting results. Error: {e}", flush=True)

    save = to_csv(parsed_results,args.filename,)
    
    print(f"CSV file saved to: {save}")


def build_query(start_date, end_date, forwarder):

    start_date = "now-1d/d"
    end_date = "now/d"


    print(forwarder)
    query = {
        "size": 10_000,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "analyze_wildcard": True,
                            "default_field": "message",
                            "query": f'forwarder:"{forwarder}" AND (host.keyword:/LN.*/ OR host.keyword:/PC.*/ OR host.keyword:/TB.*/)',  # noqa: E501
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": start_date,
                                "lte": end_date,
                                "time_zone": LOCAL_UTC_OFF_SET,
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ],
                "must_not": [],
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "1": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "dest_host.keyword",
                    "size": 9_999,
                    "shard_size": 9_999,
                    "order": {"_count": "asc"},
                },
            },
        },
    }
    return query
```

It seems i cant create a new argument in here...

Comment: This is a python programming problem. You are returning the query on the first iteration. Do you want a list of queries for each of those forward IDs? If so, simply append the query to a list and return the list once you iterate all the forwarders.

Comment: Ohh, i think i get what your saying, how should i go about going through the list?

Comment: Can i put the list of forwarders in my main() function and pass in the variable forwarders?

Comment: it all depends on how you structure your program. Its just code, as long as it does what you want, who cares.

Comment: updated with main() function and what i tried, i tried adding a new arguement and it didnt like it